# How can I get a various strings inside different curly braces?

Tags: java

Imagine I have a String like this:

```
String str = "{} {2,3,4} {1} {6} {}";
```

And I want to obtain an array filled with the information inside the curly braces so the array would look like this:

```
array[0] = NULL, array[1] = "2,3,4", array[2] = "1", array[3] = "6", array[4] = NULL
```

I was thinking on maybe splitting the initial string `str` and then using some kind of regex to obtain what is inside the the curly braces.
Is there any easier and more elegant way to do this?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did `str` come from?

Comment: A file containing the description of an DFA/NFA. @Rogue

Comment: I think regex in this situation will give you headaches. I think its easier to write a simple parser. Take a look at something called recursive descent parsers.

Comment: And just for the record: I wouldn't use null, but simply the empty string "" for "empty braces. Null values are always the first 50 percent of running into null pointer exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regex very less string operations.
works faster, i believe

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("->" + matcher.group().replaceAll("[{}]",""));
        }
```

Comment: Really helpful solution @Jigar Gajjar I really did not think of grouping and replacing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're all spaced the same way and always follow a rule with brackets:

```
public List<Integer> parseList(String list) {
    Stream.of(list.split(",")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

List<List<Integer>> automata = Stream.of(str.split("\\s")) //split into groups of braces
    .map(s -> s.substring(1, s.length() - 2)) //remove braces
    .map(Example::parseList) //map "1,2,3" into a List of [1,2,3]
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Each `List<Integer>` in `automata` is a list of integers involved in a singular DFA/NFA. No regex necessary, and took about 2 minutes to write (To nod towards what @JamMaster is saying).

That said, in the true spirit of DFA you could write a character-by-character parser which works through the string in O(n) time. Might be worth extra credit if you did both.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ill give it a try with your answer and definitely will give a look to what @JamMaster said!